# Work in other EU countries while I have temporary Residence permit in Lithuania

Tags: visa, resident-permit

I am iOS Developer and co-founder of a startup in Lithuania and as non-EU citizen I have startup visa and temporary residence permit in Lithuania. Do I have permission to looking for job in other EU countries like Netherland? Can I apply for residency in that country? What is the rules for looking for a job in another country if I am already in EU?

Comment: Because I have Schengen visa and already in Europe, after make contract with a company, Do I need to ask the embassy or migration department?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, your working permit is limited to Lithuania, and you cannot work with Lithuania's work permit in any other EU country.

If you wish to work in other countries, you have to get the work permit of that country first.

In order to obtain the work permit, you must first make contract with a company in that country, and then ask the embassy to give you the work permit.